# How to fix dart 2 mysql not working and sqlkocky package?

Tags: mysql, dart, sqljocky

I want to connect mysql database using dart sqljocky package but it's not compatible. dart analysis show error.

```
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.0.0.

Because dartAuth depends on sqljocky >=0.1.3 which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because dartAuth depends on sqljocky >=0.1.3 which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.

According to the error, the installed version of the Dart SDK is too new for the sqljocky version required by dartAuth.

You'll either need to downgrade to a pre-2.0.0 version of the Dart SDK or upgrade to a dartAuth version that doesn't require an outdated version of sqljocky (which hasn't been updated in three years).

It's not clear from your post, but it looks to me like you must be using a very old version of dartAuth if it's depending on sqljocky, so moving to a newer version of the former and replacing the latter with something that's actively maintained seem to be reasonable first steps.